# MSbuild and project optimization

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm using MSbuild class for compile visual studio 2010 projects from module of my programm.
But I can't find how to tell compiler which optimization flags it must use. 
There is only Optimize property on MSBuild and only  tag at .vcxproj file. But I want to play with such compiler switch like /Os /Ot /Oi etc. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is standard [CL Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee862477.aspx)  in MSBuild, which is represented by

```
<ClCompile>
```

tag in .vcxproj file. So it's possible to playing with compiler switches via Parameters of this task